# Center elements vertically inside UINavigationBar with custom height

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm developing an iOS 6 and 7 app that requires the navigation bar to be taller than the usual 44/64 pts 
I've searched high and low and so far it seems the cleanest solution is to use a category (or subclass) and implement the `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` method to return a different size.

This works fine in just making , however doing this causes all the items inside to rest at the bottom of the navigation bar, while I'd like to have them centered.
I have tried using the Appearance Proxy protocol to define vertical offsets for the buttons, specifically this code

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment: -10    forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment: -10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment: -10 forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Works just fine on iOS 6, producing this result

[image: iOS 6]

But doesn't work on iOS 7, giving me this instead.

[image: iOS 7]

I have read around that under iOS 7 the adjustments only work when using custom views but it seems odd to me, especially considering that `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` actually moves the text for the back button up, but not the chevron and that the title actually does nudge up.

I've also tried going for a subclassing route, using layoutSubviews to move down the views inside the UINavigationBar.
This works, but of course when a new view controller is pushed the buttons jump around during the transition.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** I have edited the description to make it clearer that my issue is with what's inside the bar, not the bar itself.

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest solution I've found to this problem was to use my own subclass of `UINavigationBar` and center the buttons vertically by overriding the `layoutSubviews` method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *subviews = self.subviews;
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            view.frame = ({
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                CGFloat navigationBarHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
                CGFloat buttonHeight = CGRectGetHeight(view.frame);
                frame.origin.y = (navigationBarHeight - buttonHeight) / 2.0f;
                frame;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

To make a `UINavigationController` use your subclass of `UINavigationBar` you can use the `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:` initialiser:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
```

Comment: I have investigated this route too, but it causes cosmetic issues when pushing and popping view controllers.

Comment: I'm not having any problems pushing/popping, but maybe that is because I have a `UINavigationBar` with the standard height. In iOS 7, however, my `UIBarButtonItem`s were not being centered vertically correctly and this solved it. Sorry I couldn't be of help.

Comment: It's OK, I think this one simply cannot be done. I ended up using a horrible workaround that involves creating buttons with custom UIView's that are as high as the navigation bar and adding buttons there. It ain't pretty, but it works

Comment: I like this `view.frame = ({ expression; })` sorcery! Didn't know you could do that. ;-)

Comment: Works gread for buttons but have issues with titleView. If I go with repositioning all the views - it messes up the layout and repositions the status bar background view as well. Do you have any solution for repositioning titleView?

Comment: I just found a solution for centering the titleView as well. In the view controller, just assign it a tag of a random number such as 999, and then when checking if the view is UIButton, add an or statement to check if it has a tag of 999.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the following code to your `viewDidLoad` Method :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

It is quickly explained in Apple migrating to iOS 7 Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

//it's leave the status-bar height above.

Comment: U can Also use Delta property using down your view 20pixels below.It's just happen for because ios7 into full screen give to developer for manage itself.

Comment: No, this isn't about the navigation bar overlapping the status bar... I've got that part already handled by my storyboards. What I need is to properly center the contents of the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

**There is a quick crack to this, unless you find the proper solution, this would definitely work ;)**

- *Check for system running iOS7.*

  ```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
  {
     // Add below code
  }
  ```
- *Add Label to the Navigation Bar :*

  ```
  UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 55, 150, 20)]; //Set the frame appropriate to your screen
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
  label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
  label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  [bar addSubview:label];
  ```

Comment: But this simply makes the bar bigger right? My issue is with the vertical positioning of the items inside

Comment: Nopes .. did you tested it ? This won't increase the height, instead it will allow you to set the position of label in the bar.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it. But the title label is fine (``setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment`` does the job fine), my problem is with the back button resting at the bottom of the bar instead of the middle (on iOS 7, iOS 6 works just fine)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of Tiago his answer

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    subviews.filter { (subview) -> Bool in
        return subview is UIButton
    }.forEach { (subview) in
        subview.center.y = frame.height / 2
    }
}
```

Adjusting the titleView vertical postion

```
setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change size of navigation bar with just changing it's frame:

> CGRect navigationBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

Comment: It may be quicker but it doesn't fix the issue with the buttons sticking to the bottom of the navigation bar